# How to parse a XML dom from a string?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, dom

It is possible to build a XML DOM from scratch:

```
var data = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
data.appendChild(data.createElement("data"));
```

But I can not find a method which builds an XML DOM from a string (not URL):

```
var data = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
data.parse_document("<data/>");
```

Do I have to write the `parse_document` from scratch or is it available somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in your question, it looks like you're doing this on a browser.

If so, you can use `DOMParser` if it's available, falling back (on IE) to an active X object.

```
function parseXML(str) {
    var xmlDoc, parser;
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
    } else {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(str);
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

Note that `parseXML` will throw an exception on invalid XML.

Comment: I see. I was looking at the wrong place for this function.

Comment: IE >= 9 supports DOMParser, too.

Comment: @ThW: Hence the feature detection rather than browser detection. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to T.J Crowder's answer, [The Definitive Guide](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/definitive2/2.html) includes a third option:

```
var url = 'data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, false);
if (request.overrideMimeType) {
    request.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
}
request.send(null);
return request.responseXML;
```

Comment: What is the [maximum length](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/402322) of a purely local get request?

Comment: This is an interesting but less efficient solution, because it makes it necessary to craft the request. The concatenation copies the XML string and the encoding also at least once, maybe even more than once.

Comment: @ceving Just another fallback. The last option.